# Where to put my sqlalchemy code in my script?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I had my sqlalchemy related code in my main() method in my script.

But then when I created a function, I wasn't able to reference my 'products' mapper because it was in the main() method.

Should I be putting the sqlalchemy related code (session, mapper, and classes) in global scope so all functions in my single file script can refer to it?

I was told a script is usually layout out as:

globals
functions
classes
main

But if I put sqlalchemy at the top to make it global, I have to move my classes to the top also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical approach is to define all mappings in separate `model` module, with one file per class/table.

Then you just import needed classes whenever need them.